# How to replace one line in php?

Tags: php, file, design-patterns

I have test.txt file, like this,

```
AA=1
BB=2
CC=3
```

Now I wanna find "BB=" and replace it as BB=5, like this,

```
AA=1
BB=5
CC=3
```

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi guys, I got the answer, $str = preg_replace('/BB=\d/', 'BB=5', $str);  I think this is the better way, right?

Comment: In this case you need to read the complete file in a string variable , run preg_replace and overwrite the file with the new string variable.

Comment: Correct, (see my comment below :) )

Comment: hi Varun Mittal and Aaron Murray, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your file is structured like an INI file (i.e. key=value), you could use [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) and do something like this:

```
<?php

$filename = 'file.txt';

// Parse the file assuming it's structured as an INI file.
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php
$data = parse_ini_file($filename);

// Array of values to replace.
$replace_with = array(
  'BB' => 5
);

// Open the file for writing.
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w');

// Loop through the data.
foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
{
  // If a value exists that should replace the current one, use it.
  if ( ! empty($replace_with[$key]) )
    $value = $replace_with[$key];

  // Write to the file.
  fwrite($fh, "{$key}={$value}" . PHP_EOL);
}

// Close the file handle.
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: very nice +1 :) thats what happens when you work too much with frameworks, you forget all about cool stuff like parse_ini_file :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

    $file = "data.txt";
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($fp)) {
    $data = fgets($fp, 1024);

    // You have the data in $data, you can write replace logic 
    Replace Logic function
    $data will store the final value

    // Write back the data to the same file 
     $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
     fwrite($Handle, $data); 


    echo "$data <br>";
    }
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

The above peace of code will give you data from the file and helps you to write the data back to the file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (if you are talking about a small file as above), would be something like:

```
    // Read the file in as an array of lines
    $fileData = file('test.txt');

    $newArray = array();
    foreach($fileData as $line) {
      // find the line that starts with BB= and change it to BB=5
      if (substr($line, 0, 3) == 'BB=')) {
        $line = 'BB=5';
      }
      $newArray[] = $line;
    }

    // Overwrite test.txt
    $fp = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, implode("\n",$newArray));
    fclose($fp);
```

(something like that)

Comment: hi Aaron Murray, thanks.it's small file, but around 50 line。 If I have 50 lines need to replace, and every time we do for loop, I think it cost lots of resources.

Comment: @heefan Ok, I thought you just wanted an overview of how to read/write.  You could also use $fileData = file_get_contents('test.txt') which would read it in as a string rather than an array and then use regex patterns to search the data/manipulate the data and then write it back out to the file.

Comment: @heefan the quick and dirty way to do it is to read the entire file in as either a string or an array, manipulate it as necessary and then overwrite the file (or write to a new file) the updated information.

Comment: Are you sure about that? This is still plenty efficient - you're not even parsing an XML file into an object. Unless you're running this loop hundreds of times a second on a microprocessor from the 80's, it should be plenty fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pear package for find & replace text in a file .

For more information read

```
http://www.codediesel.com/php/search-replace-in-files-using-php/
```

Comment: sorry, I cannot, I am using embedded OS, the php without pear support.